# Model Epidemic Random Graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, random-graphs

I'm reading on random graphs and understand that they can be used to model disease spread (seems particularly germane at the moment). The papers I've found so far are focused on quite complex models. I'm wondering if someone could point me to explanation of or explain how a random graph could be used to model a disease with a simple set of assumptions. For example,

Uniform infection transfer from an infected individual to others.
People can only be infected once.
No countermeasures.

I'm trying to understand what exactly it means to model an epidemic with a random graph but am struggling with the complexity of the examples I've found so far. Thank you.

Comment: This is the standard reference https://www.amazon.com/Dynamical-Processes-Complex-Networks-Barrat/dp/1107626250